Regularity of weak solution of elliptic equation with nonlinear Neumann boundary
Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded smooth domain and $u \in W^{1,2}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^m)$ be a weak solution to the following equation
\begin{align*}
&\int_{\Omega} \nabla u \cdot \nabla \psi+f(u)\cdot\psi dx
+\int_{\partial \Omega}g(u)\cdot\psi d \mathcal{H}^{n-1}_x=0
\end{align*}
for any $\psi \in W^{1,2}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^m)$, where $f$ and $g$ are some smooth functions. The above equation comes from some energy minimization problems. However, I cannot find any related results on the nonlinear Neumann boundary problems. I could like to ask how we could establish the regularity of the above equation.
Suppose that $u$ is bounded on $\Omega$, the interior regularity is not a problem. I do not know how to deal with the boundary regularity. After a transformation, we assume that the boundary is flat and thus we can use the difference quotient method. However there is a difference quotient of $u$ on the boundary, which is hard to deal with. Any good books or references for it? Thanks!

Finally got some ideas in Theorem 3.3 of 'Quasilinear elliptic and parabolic Robin problems on Lipschitz domains' by Robin Nittka. The idea is to first flatten the boundary locally and then reflect the solution across the flat boundary. Next, we apply the trace theorem and Hahn-Banach theorem to extend the boundary integral to a integral on a open set containing the flat boundary. But it only shows the Holder continuity up to the boundary, I think the $C^2$-regularity is completed if we can show that $u \in H^2$. But I do not have any thought yet.

Finally got the answer in the book of Grisvard Elliptic Problems in Nonsmooth Domains. First we find a solution $u_1$ solving $\Delta u_1=-u_1$ on $\Omega$ and $\partial u_1/\partial n = -g(u)$ by Corollary 2.2.2.6 there. Then, we consider the equation $u_1-u$ and find that the boundary is zero. Next, we apply the difference quotient method to obtain the $H^2$ regularity. Bootstrapping results are referred to Theorem 2.5.1.1 there.
